# How do I extract an exact word from text by using python?

Tags: python

I want to calculate how many lines contain a word matched with keywords I chosen. So I coded like this.

```
  28         for each_keyword in keywords:
  29             if each_keyword in text:
  31                 related_tweet_count += 1
  32                 print "related_tweet_count", related_tweet_count
  33                 print text
```

It performed very well. But it has a problem. For example, I have a keyword "flu" then it gives not only "flu" but also "influence". To solve this problem, I searched match word examples and fixed the code like this.

```
  28         for each_keyword in keywords:
  30             if re.search('\beach_keyword\b', text, re.I):
  31                 related_tweet_count += 1
  32                 print "related_tweet_count", related_tweet_count
  33                 print text
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to actually substitute `each_keyword` into the regular expression.  At the moment it's literally trying to match "each_keyword".

```
28         for each_keyword in keywords:
30             if re.search('\\b' + each_keyword + '\\b', text, re.I):
31                 related_tweet_count += 1
32                 print "related_tweet_count", related_tweet_count
33                 print text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Before I put the question I tried to use "if re.search('\b' + each_keyword + '\b', text, re.I):" and it didn't work. I forgot the usage of "\\".

Comment: No problem.  I've found sometimes `\x` will work, probably if it's not a valid string escape sequence, but for consistency it's best to always use `\\x`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively do it without regular expressions and use more kw variations,

```
for keyword in keywords:
    kw_list = [' '+keyword+',',' '+keyword+' ',' '+keyword+'.','. '+keyword]
    for kw in kw_list:
        if kw in text:
            related_tweet_count += 1
```